# How to return lowest value from dictionary object with selected tags?

Tags: python

How can I return lowest value from dictionary object with selected tags

```
findLowestQty(inputstring,'Qty')
```

InputString:

```
{
1235 : {'Id':1, 'Qty' : 25},
1236 : {'Id':2, 'Qty' : 35},
1237 : {'Id':3, 'Qty' : 15},
1238 : {'Id':4, 'Qty' : 45}
}

Output : ('1237', 15)
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a list comprehension like so:

```
i = {
1235 : {'Id':1, 'Qty' : 25},
1236 : {'Id':2, 'Qty' : 35},
1237 : {'Id':3, 'Qty' : 15},
1238 : {'Id':4, 'Qty' : 45}
}
w = 'Qty'
b = min([d[w] for k, d in i.items()])
a = [j for j in i if i[j][w] == b]
print((str(a[0]), b))
```

Output:

```
('1237', 15)
```

Comment: That will give tuple `print(min([(key, value['Qty']) for key, value in i.items()]))`

Comment: @RichardKYu I fixed my answer.

Comment: @NixonSparrow that finds the min key not the min value though.